# How to deploy an AWS Kinesis Data Analytics App without downtime

Tags: continuous-integration, apache-flink, continuous-deployment, cicd, amazon-kinesis-analytics

We currently have an **AWS Kinesis Data Analytics app** that requires a **.jar** file to run.

We have automated the deployment for our .jar file that resides in an S3 bucket.

[image: Config]

Our issue is, whenever the .jar file is updated we are forced to    restart the kinesis app to get the new build which is causing **downtime**

Does anyone have a workaround or another way of deploying the app **Without causing downtime** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink itself does not support zero-downtime deployments. While a few users have built their own solutions for this, it requires implementing application-specific deployment automation and tooling. See

- [Drivetribe's Modern Take On CQRS With Apache Flink](https://www.ververica.com/blog/drivetribe-cqrs-apache-flink)
- [Zero-downtime upgrades of Flink applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hyt3YrtKQAM)

for examples.